# OpenGL glBindTexture() crash

Tags: c++, opengl

The program freezes when I call glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _ID); in the draw(Sprite) method of the 'Renderer' class. (the actual code is sprite.getTexture()->bind(), but I have added a std::cout in that function before and after the glBindTexture() call and it only prints once).

I am struggling to understand why the program is freezing - when I call glBindTexture, the program doesn't respond and crashes. Rather than filing this page up with a long list of code, heres the link to the github: https://github.com/TheInfernalcow/OpenGL-game, the files which are relevant are mainly the src/graphics/renderer.cpp and src/graphics/texture.cpp.

If anyone has the time to read through the code and try and point me in the right direction I would be grateful, have been pondering over this for hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it `Splashstate` that is having issue? If so -

```
SplashState::SplashState(Game* game)
{
    _game = game;
    Texture2D backgroundTexture("res/darkguy.png", 96, 128);
    Sprite _background;
    _background.setTexture(backgroundTexture);
}
```

You are assigning a texture to the locally scoped `Sprite`, not the one on the `SplashState` -- so when you try to draw it in your render function, the class level `Sprite` has no texture.

Comment: Yep, deleting the 'Sprite _background' line solved the problem don't know why i declared that twice

Comment: It happens (especially before coffee)! Can you mark as solved?